# Does there exist a test vector for the Xoodoo permutation?

Tags: test-vectors, lightweight

What I need is a set of pairs, where the first element of the pair is a 384-bit input (including the sequence of 384 zero bits) and the second element is a corresponding 384-bit output of the [Xoodoo permutation](https://eprint.iacr.org/2018/767). Does such a test vector exist?

Comment: reference implementation : https://github.com/KeccakTeam/Xoodoo